# iOS: When to use delegate/dataSource (protocols) vs. properties

Tags: ios, swift

Many CocoaPod and native iOS libraries use protocols that they name either `CustomClassDelegate` or `CustomClassDataSource` as a means to do some setup or customization. I was wondering when I should use this programming model, because it seems like I could accomplish much of this with properties.

**Example**

If I define a custom class called `SmurfViewController` that has a `SmurfLabel`, is it better practice to store the `smurfLabel` as a private property and have a public *computed* property called `smurf` that looks like this:

```
private var smurfLabel = UILabel()
public var smurf: String {
  get {
    return smurfLabel.text
  }
  set(text) {
    smurfLabel.text = text
  }
}
```

or should I define a `SmurfDataSource` that has a public function that looks like this:

```
func textForSmurfLabel() -> String {
  return "smurfText"
}
```

When should I use what here?

Comment: You cannot achieve the same using properties. As far as I know Protocols are custom delegate methods used by user to notify other classes when a certain action is done.

Comment: You can use callbacks instead of delegates. In fact it is encouraged. Nice tutorial: https://medium.cobeisfresh.com/why-you-shouldn-t-use-delegates-in-swift-7ef808a7f16b#.erlmejwjo

Comment: Implicit in the comments/answers here, delegate-protocol pattern is a way for one class to inform another of some event. Typically when considering delegates, you compare delegate-protocol pattern against other notification patterns such as callback closures, notifications, observers, etc. Properties, themselves, are a different thing altogether, designed to allow an external object the ability to inquire about the state of some object, but not for the proactive notification of some state change.

Answer (score 1):

You should just use a property for that. Delegates and Datasources are for different controllers/Objects to speak to one another when the alternative is to instantiate the controller/object from the navigationStack/view hierarchy. A Delegate forms a specific communication between the two that allows for clear knowledge in what their relationship is while keeping them decoupled (assuming you try to keep it that way). I disagree with the article that says callbacks are "better". They are amazing and I advise using them often, but just understand that most options that swift provides you with have a place where they work best.

I might be slightly bias, but Swift is an amazing language with OOP being a backbone and everything it has was well put together in order to provide the correct tools for each situation you find yourself in.

I often find myself using both of those tools and one other more customizable option in my more advanced setups where I have an overseeing viewController that manages many child controllers. It has direct access to all of them that are active but if any of its children communicate with it, it is through delegates. Its main job is just to handle their place on the screen though, so I keep everything manageable.

Answer (score 0):

Delegates and data sources are more appropriate for offloading *behaviors* to other entities, not simple values. In other words, if your type just needs a value for something, you are correct that it makes more sense to expose that as a property that can be set from the client code.

But what should happen (for example) when a user taps a specific table view cell is a behavior that shouldn't be hard coded into UITableView. Instead, for flexibility, any implementation of that behavior can be created in a delegate and called by the UITableView when appropriate.

In general, think of delegation as a way to make subclassing unnecessary, because the methods you would normally override in a subclass are instead moved into a protocol that can be implemented by ANY type, not just a subclass of the base type. And instead of calling internally implemented methods to get certain behaviors, your type is simply calling those behaviors on an external collaborating class (the delegate).

So perhaps the best guideline for when to use a data source or delegate is the question: "Would I need to subclass this class in order to change this value or behavior in the future".  If the answer is no, because you can just set a property from client code, then don't use delegation.  If the answer is yes, then offload that behavior to a delegate or data source instead of forcing future programmers to subclass your class to make it work for their use case.

Comment: I would add that simple values which are queried often *and that may change frequently* are best queried through a protocol.  This is what a `UITableView` does for section and row counts, for example.  The reason this is better is that the provider can place the code to compute the value, if such code is needed, in one place.  If those were properties, the provider would potentially have to set them from many locations in the code.  That would be messy.

Answer (score 0):

Delegate is an interface for the undefined activities.
so when you make a SDK or framework, you must provide an interface so that users can write a proper code for the interfaces' expecting activity.

i.e, Table View needs a datasource to show it's contents, but the apple's library developers doesn't know the content whatever contents their library users will use. so they provided an interface like datasource, delegate. 
and in the library, they just call this methods. that's the way the library should be made.

But in your code, the label is defined very explicitly as well as it's in the current view, and you don't need to make an interface for an undefined activity.

if you want know more about this kind of coding style, you need to do some researches on Software Design Pattern.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern

I love apple's sdk very much, because they used all the needed design patterns very properly.